# Change string.xml at runtime

Tags: android, runtime

I have a special request to implement dynamic language packs and themes in Android. This basically means:

1. to download a zip file containing a file named strings.xml (containing the translation)
2. replace in the application the file /res/values/strings.xml with the one downloaded

Is this possible? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

No. Things inside the Res folder are static and you can't recreate the `R` class in runtime.

Why don't you try using sqlite for your situation?

Comment: I will be forced in this case to "manually" translate all the interface. Not really an option. I am not sure if another option exists, maybe a 3rd party library allowing skinning and multilanguage with external files.

Comment: Not really. You can add a condition such as  `WHERE language = 'french'` to retrieve a specific language